# Graphs that are not $\mathbb{R}^2$-realizable

Tags: graph-theory, real-analysis

We say that a finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$-*realizable* if there is an injective map $\varphi:V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for $v\neq w \in V$ we have $\{v,w\} \in E$ if and only if $|\varphi(v)-\varphi(w)| < 1$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean distance.

What is an example of a finite graph that is not $\mathbb{R}^2$-realizable?

Comment: Those are precisely the [unit disk graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph) (to replace the inequality by a strict one, scale the graph by a factor slightly smaller than $1$).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about the [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) $S_6$? To realize this graph in the way you describe, you would have to map the center point to some $c \in \mathbb R^2$; then you would need to map the $6$ other points of $S_6$ inside the unit circle around $c$, but all at distance $\geq\!1$ from each other. This is impossible.